# In Rust, how can you call an async function from a C callback that was called from a tokio context?

Tags: rust-tokio

From inside a tokio context (though not in an async fn), I am calling a C library function, which in turn calls a callback in my code. I want my callback to be able to spawn an async task and then return without waiting for it.

The code compiles, but at runtime it fails immediately. The error is shown after the code sample.

Here's some pseudo/sample code that demonstrates the structure of my real code:

```
///
/// Start several different poller top-level tasks and 
/// wait for them all to complete
///
async fn start_and_wait_for_pollers() {

    //
    // start multiple pollers
    //
    let mut tokio_join_set = tokio::task::JoinSet::new();
    for _i in 0..5 {
        tokio_join_set.spawn(async {
            poll_for_work()
        });
    }

    //
    // wait for all pollers to complete
    //
    while let Some(res) = tokio_join_set.join_next().await {
        if let Err(e) = res {
            warn!("Error joining poller: {:?}", e);
        }
    };
}




///
/// Loop indefinitely, polling for work to do until there's no more work to do.
///
fn poll_for_work() {
    loop {
        // call into C library, which blocks until there is work to do, 
        // and then for each work item it finds, it synchronously calls our 
        // start_work_callback() function once for each work item, and 
        // finally returning how many work items it started via calling 
        // start_work_callback()
        let work_cnt = unsafe { my_c_lib::poll_for_work() };
        if work_cnt < 0 {
            info!("No more work to do; exiting poll_for_work()");
            break;
        }
    }
}


///
/// Callback function called from C library function 
/// my_c_lib::poll_for_work() whenever it detects there is a
/// work item to do.  This function should start the work 
/// asynchronously and then return quickly
///
extern "C" fn start_work_callback(work_item_id: cty::c_int) -> cty::c_int {

    //
    // We stash the tokio runtime handle in a global variable so we 
    // can get access to it here, as it can't be passed in, as we don't 
    // control the signature of the callback  (it is defined by the C library).
    //
    let tokio_handle: Handle;
    unsafe {
        match GLOBALS.global_tokio_handle.as_ref() {
            None => {
                log::warn!("No global tokio handle set inside start_io_fn");
                return -1;
            }
            Some(global_tokio_handle) => {
                tokio_handle = global_tokio_handle.clone();
            }
        }
    };

    //
    // Block on starting the work
    let result = tokio_handle.block_on(     //  <------- this panics
        start_work()
    );
    if let Err(err) = result {
        warn!("Failed to start work for {}", work_item_id);
        return -1;  
    }

    return 0;

}



async fn start_work() -> Result<(), String> {
    // do some synchronous stuff

    // await a few async tasks
    do_something_async().await?;
    do_something_else_async().await?;

    // Spawn an async task to we don't want to wait for
    tokio::spawn(do_some_slow_stuff());

    Ok(())
}
```

The code all compiles ok, but at runtime, the call to tokio_handle.block_on() panics, and I see the following in the logs:

> thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.

How can I fix this? That is, how can I make an async call from within a C callback function whose calling C function was itself called from within a tokio context?

Comment: I realize now that tokio_handle.block_on() not only waits for the future to complete, it blocks the current thread while doing so.  So I get why that's bad.

Is it possible to tell Rust that the extern C was called from a tokio context, i.e. mark it async (but not return a future) so that it can await other async functions?